# Joomla datepicker field issue

Tags: templates, form, form-fields-types

Can someone help please?

I'm working on a simple component which displays events.  The component allows events to be submitted from the frontend.  The form uses the Joomla datepicker.

The problem I'm experiencing is when I click on a date in the datepicker it doesn't populate/fill the field. The placeholder doesn't show either.  Also, I can't manually type in the field.

I also have an equivalent form in the backend which also uses the datepicker and that works just fine.

One interesting thing I've discovered is, if I switch from my template to the 'protostar' template I still experience the problem, but if I switch to the 'Beez3' template the datepicker and field works perfectly.

What am I missing?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are we able to see anything in terms of code, source code, generated client-side errors?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure what code to show you.  Saying that, I believe it to be a template issue because everything works fine with the Beez3 template but not my template or the Protostar template.  So, what does the Beez3 template have (or possibly not) compared to my template and the Protostar template?  No client-side errors are produced that I can see.

Comment: I've add a 'Developer Tools' snippet (image) above.

Comment: What happens if on the same page you just echo out a calendar field using: `<?php echo JHtml::calendar(); ?>` ?

Comment: Hi @Zollie.  I get an error saying too few arguments, expecting 3.

Comment: It's just odd that it works fine with the Beez3 template and the administrator template but not with the Protostar and my template.

Comment: Of course because that method needs some arguments, but I thought that you might know this, so I give you a sample including some arguments for trying: `<?php echo JHtml::calendar(“2019-12-24”, "field-calendar-150", "jform-field-150", '%Y-%m-%d'); ?>`

Comment: The reason I give you another approach to create this sample field because this way we can see that the problem is with the field anyway or with creating it via xml or somewhere else... it is just one step to close out possibilities.

Comment: Sorry @Zollie, I realised this after and added the arguments and it displayed perfectly.  I did switch on development mode and no errors showing.

Comment: Good! Does the displayed calendar field work? And the others do not? Or ?

Comment: Applying your suggestion led me to compare it's output with the input field and doing this helped me find the issue.  Believe it or not it was a CSS issue.  The datepicker input field had a font size of 100% (All the other input fields didn't) which forced the content out of the field.  Overflow was also hidden.  Adjusting this sorted it!  Thanks for all your help @Zollie, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Great! I’m happy that you found the problem!

Comment: Please create a short but descriptive answer from what you found and you can accept that as a solution. That way the question will be closed with a useful answer and probably will help someone later.